# Error building the application - see the log above

Tags: react-native, expo

```
[RUN_FASTLANE] ⚠️  ld: duplicate method '+moduleName' in
┌─[category]: ExpoBridgeModule-a2f7ea2dc6021c07c320eefe65ede09e.o ExpoModulesCore/libExpoModulesCore.a
└─[class]: ExpoBridgeModule-eab3a5e9b0aa20a3785880c65c026883.o ExpoModulesCore/libExpoModulesCore.a

[RUN_FASTLANE] ⚠️  ld: method '+UIStatusBarAnimation:' in category from /Users/abdel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-eqlapbgdutmjeuhjrmfdvnhgjomz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myapp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-CoreModules/libReact-CoreModules.a(RCTStatusBarManager.o) conflicts with same method from another category
[RUN_FASTLANE] › Generating debug myapp » myapp.app.dSYM
[RUN_FASTLANE] › Executing myapp » Bundle React Native code and images
[RUN_FASTLANE]     the transform cache was reset.
[RUN_FASTLANE]     the variable "navigator" was not declared in anonymous function " 618#"
[RUN_FASTLANE] › Executing myapp » [CP] Copy Pods Resources
[RUN_FASTLANE] › Executing parmyappafeel » [CP] Embed Pods Frameworks
[RUN_FASTLANE] › Signing   myapp » myapp.app
[RUN_FASTLANE] › Creating  myapp » myapp.app
[RUN_FASTLANE]     Run script build phase '[CP-User] Generate app.config for prebuilt Constants.manifest' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'EXConstants' from project 'Pods')
[RUN_FASTLANE]     Run script build phase '[CP-User] Generate app.manifest for expo-updates' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'EXUpdates' from project 'Pods')
[RUN_FASTLANE] ▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
[RUN_FASTLANE] ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
[RUN_FASTLANE] Exit status: 65
[RUN_FASTLANE]
[RUN_FASTLANE] +-------------+-------------------------+
[RUN_FASTLANE] |           Build environment           |
[RUN_FASTLANE] +-------------+-------------------------+
[RUN_FASTLANE] | xcode_path  | /Applications/Xcode.app |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | gym_version | 2.213.0                 |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | sdk         | iPhoneOS16.2.sdk        |
[RUN_FASTLANE] +-------------+-------------------------+
[RUN_FASTLANE] Looks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project
[RUN_FASTLANE] It's hard to tell what's causing the error, so we wrote some guides on how
[RUN_FASTLANE] to troubleshoot build and signing issues: https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/
[RUN_FASTLANE] Before submitting an issue on GitHub, please follow the guide above and make
[RUN_FASTLANE] sure your project is set up correctly.
[RUN_FASTLANE] fastlane uses `xcodebuild` commands to generate your binary, you can see the
[RUN_FASTLANE] the full commands printed out in yellow in the above log.
[RUN_FASTLANE] Make sure to inspect the output above, as usually you'll find more error information there
[RUN_FASTLANE]
[RUN_FASTLANE] [!] Error building the application - see the log above
[RUN_FASTLANE] Error: The "Run fastlane" step failed with an unknown error. Refer to "Xcode Logs" below for additional, more detailed logs.
[CLEAN_UP_CREDENTIALS] Destroying keychain - /var/folders/lx/q5y7b9jx68ngd58grm3zvbp40000gn/T/turtle-v2-c271f5db-819d-4c86-a4ac-5bf7f6ce7cb5.keychain
[CLEAN_UP_CREDENTIALS] Removing provisioning profile

Build failed
The "Run fastlane" step failed with an unknown error. Refer to "Xcode Logs" below for additional, more detailed logs.
npx exited with non-zero code: 1
    Error: build command failed.
```

m encountering an error while trying to build my React Native app for iOS. The error message states: "Error: above

I have already tried reinstalling the project dependencies using npm install, but the error still persists. I'm using Node.js v18.0.0, and I have confirmed that both Node.js and npm are installed on my system. However, the 'execa' module seems to be missing.

I would appreciate any help or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. What steps can I take to troubleshoot and fix this error? Are there any specific dependencies or configurations I need to check in my project?

Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!
Here is my packege.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.7.5",
    "@eva-design/eva": "^2.1.1",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@freakycoder/react-native-bounceable": "^1.0.3",
    "@freakycoder/react-native-helpers": "^2.0.2",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.4.5",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.2.8",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.16",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.7",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@shopify/flash-list": "1.4.0",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.70.6",
    "@ui-kitten/components": "^5.1.2",
    "@ui-kitten/eva-icons": "^5.1.2",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^3.0.1",
    "deserialize-json-api": "^1.4.0",
    "dlv": "^1.1.3",
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "expo-application": "~5.1.1",
    "expo-asset": "~8.9.1",
    "expo-auth-session": "~4.0.3",
    "expo-av": "~13.2.1",
    "expo-background-fetch": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.6.0",
    "expo-clipboard": "~4.1.2",
    "expo-constants": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.2.1",
    "expo-dev-launcher": "^2.1.5",
    "expo-font": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-linking": "~4.0.1",
    "expo-localization": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.18.1",
    "expo-random": "~13.1.1",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "~5.1.1",
    "expo-sharing": "~11.2.2",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "expo-task-manager": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-updates": "~0.16.4",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.1.1",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "i18n-js": "^4.2.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "kitsu-core": "^8.3.1",
    "lodash.find": "^4.6.0",
    "lodash.get": "^4.4.2",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.4",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.0",
    "patch-package": "^6.5.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-error-boundary": "^3.1.4",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.40.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.3",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.3.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-logs": "^5.0.1",
    "react-native-mmkv": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.14.0",
    "react-native-reanimated-carousel": "^3.1.5",
    "react-native-redash": "^16.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-shared-element": "^0.8.7",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.8.0",
    "react-native-truncated-text-view": "^0.3.2",
    "react-native-youtube": "^2.0.2",
    "react-navigation-shared-element": "^3.1.3",
    "templite": "^1.2.0",
    "truncate": "^3.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "zod": "^3.19.1",
    "zustand": "^4.1.5"
  },
    "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.5",
    "@babel/generator": "^7.20.5",
    "@babel/parser": "^7.20.5",
    "@babel/traverse": "^7.20.5",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "chalk": "^4.1.2",
    "fs-extra": "^11.1.0",
    "glob": "^8.0.3",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.2"
  }
```